# Generating random values with custom PDF

Tags: python, random, scipy

I have a large dataset (over 300000 values), and I have created a PDF for it with stats.gaussian_kde as follows:

```
kernel=scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(vals)
ind=np.linspace(np.min(vals), np.max(vals),1000)
PDE=kernel.evaluate(ind)
```

Now I want to generate new random values from this pdf, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Does anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.resample) method.

```
vals = [1,2,3,4,5]
kernel = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(vals)    
my_random_vals = kernel.resample(size=10)

print(my_random_vals)
[[ 2.18467151 -1.22069121  2.64074108  0.32268845  2.78022227  6.29483273
   1.94848359  4.79865993  1.30363424  3.71441989]]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I can't believe I missed that.  It did the trick.

Comment: @MRusalka Happy to help! Remember to accept the answer so future viewers know.